# Cannot type the letter 'b' in Django Shell

Tags: python, django

My programming teacher has me doing a Django progect for my last project of the year. I've hit a big wall though. I can't use the django manage.py shell because 1 letter doesnt work. Lowercase 'b'. It just won't type. It won't copy in. I've tried through ssh and directly on the server computer. My ssh client is putty and the server is running fedora 14. Uppercase 'B' does work. I have tried from multiple computers. Please help.

Comment: Can you try running ipython directly on the server machine (type ipython).  Can you type the letter 'b'?  Can you type 'b' on the machine straight in the terminal?  This seems more an ipython/linux issue than django.

Comment: I just tried and strangely enough I can't type 'b' there either.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try running ipython directly on the server machine (type ipython). Can you type the letter 'b'? Can you type 'b' on the machine straight in the terminal? This seems more an ipython/linux issue than django.

I'm guessing that someone has bound a ipython shortcut to the letter lowercase 'b'.  This would be typically be done in '~/.ipython/ipythonrc'.  If you rename that entire directory (e.g., `mv ~/.ipython to ~/.ipython_backup`), it should be autocreated the next time you run it.  However, if some joker (or incompetent admin) modified the files in `/usr/share/pyshared/IPython/UserConfig/ipythonrc` or `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/UserConfig/ipythonrc` the new version might have the same problem as its copying from these improper locations.

If that happens, check which version of ipython you have.  When you type in ipython it should say something like: `IPython 0.10` or something with the version number.

Remember it, go to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/0.10/IPython/UserConfig (replacing the 0.10 with whatever version you have), and save/copy all those files into your ~/.ipython/ directory.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the pythonrc and I can type normally again. Thanks!